# How to include a variable-sized array as stuct member in C?

Tags: c, arrays, static, malloc, misra

I must say, I have quite a conundrum in a seemingly elementary problem. I have a structure, in which I would like to store an array as a field. I'd like to reuse this structure in different contexts, and sometimes I need a bigger array, sometimes a smaller one. C prohibits the use of variable-sized buffer. So the natural approach would be declaring a pointer to this array as struct member:

```
struct my {
    struct other* array;
}
```

The problem with this approach however, is that I have to obey the rules of MISRA-C, which prohibits dynamic memory allocation. So then if I'd like to allocate memory and initialize the array, I'm forced to do:

```
var.array = malloc(n * sizeof(...));
```

which is forbidden by MISRA standards. How else can I do this?

Comment: "*C prohibits the use of variable-sized buffer*" , Just ANSI-C or C89 prohibits this. VLAs(Variable Length Arrays) exist from C99 onwards

Comment: Right. But anyway, I cannot set it like this in a struct definition, since it won't have access to that variable anyway.

Comment: Are the different sizes (the `n`) known at compile time?

Comment: No, it's actually among *required*, not advisory constraints.

Comment: MIRA does allow pointers doesn't it, could you have a pointer to a VLA var.array = a[n]

Comment: @DaveB: he'd have to create a separate instance of each `a[n]` for each instance of his `struct` type.

Comment: @DaveB VLAs are not allowed either.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Strictly speaking, you are allowed to deviate from "required" rules, by following your MISRA-C deviation process. However, any attempt to deviate from the particular rule that's banning dynamic memory allocation is very questionable, as this is one of the more important rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: This solution does not conform to MISRA-C rules.**

You can *kind of* include VLAs in a struct definition, but only when it's inside a function.  A way to get around this is to use a "flexible array member" at the end of your main struct, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct my {
  int len;
  int array[];
};
```

You can create functions that operate on this struct.

```
void print_my(struct my *my) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < my->len; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", my->array[i]);
  }
}
```

Then, to create variable length versions of this struct, you can create a new type of struct in your function body, containing your `my` struct, but also defining a length for that buffer.  This can be done with a varying size parameter.  Then, for all the functions you call, you can just pass around a pointer to the contained `struct my` value, and they will work correctly.

```
void create_and_use_my(int nelements) {
  int i;

  // Declare the containing struct with variable number of elements.
  struct {
    struct my my;
    int array[nelements];
  } my_wrapper;

  // Initialize the values in the struct.
  my_wrapper.my.len = nelements;
  for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++) {
    my_wrapper.my.array[i] = i;
  }

  // Print the struct using the generic function above.
  print_my(&my_wrapper.my);
}
```

You can call this function with any value of `nelements` and it will work fine.  This requires C99, because it does use VLAs.  Also, there are some [GCC extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) that make this a bit easier.

**Important:** If you pass the `struct my` to another function, and not a pointer to it, I can pretty much guarantee you it will cause all sorts of errors, since it won't copy the variable length array with it.

Comment: I just made a major edit to this answer -- sorry if it messed you up while reading it.

Comment: Flexible array members as well as VLAs are also banned by MISRA. (MISRA-C 2012 18.7 and 18.8), so this solves nothing.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer to bring attention to that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are following MISRA-C, I would guess that the software is somehow mission-critical, in which case all memory allocation must be deterministic. Heap allocation is banned by every safety standard out there, not just by MISRA-C but by the more general safety standards as well (IEC 61508, ISO 26262, DO-178 and so on).

In such systems, you must always design for the worst-case scenario, which will consume the most memory. You need to allocate exactly that much space, no more, no less. Everything else does not make sense in such a system.

Given those pre-requisites, you must allocate a static buffer of size `LARGE_ENOUGH_FOR_WORST_CASE`. Once you have realized this, you simply need to find a way to keep track of what kind of data you have stored in this buffer, by using an enum and maybe a "size used" counter.

---

Please note that not just malloc/calloc, but also VLAs and flexible array members are banned by MISRA-C:2012. And if you are using C90/MISRA-C:2004, there are no VLAs, nor are there any well-defined use of flexible array members - they invoked undefined behavior until C99.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought that may be *totally* inappropriate for your situation, but given your constraints I'm not sure how else to deal with it.

Create a large static array and use this as your "heap":

```
static struct other heap[SOME_BIG_NUMBER];
```

You'll then "allocate" memory from this "heap" like so:

```
var.array = &heap[start_point];
```

You'll have to do some bookkeeping to keep track of what parts of your "heap" have been allocated.  This assumes that you don't have any major constraints on the size of your executable.